# Шаблоны в angular & ui-router

Tags: angularjs, шаблоны, angular-ui-router

Как реализовать смену layout`ов в приложении?

Есть приложение с возможностью авторизации, после авторизации нужно изменить основной layout, есть 2 layout`а: для гостя и для авторизированного пользователя.

На данный момент есть такая реализация: 
с помощью двух корневых абстрактных state`ов:

```
$stateProvider 
   // Для гостя
   .state('site', { 
      abstract: true, 
      views: { 
        '' : { templateUrl: 'site.html'},  
      } 
   }) 
   // Для авторизированного
   .state('main', { 
      abstract: true, 
      views: { 
      '' : { templateUrl: 'main.html'},  
      } 
   })
```

Потом в модулях которые доступны только авторизированным, используется родительский state "main".

```
$stateProvider
   // главная страница для гостя
   .state('site.home', { 
      url: "/", 
      views: { header: ..., body: ..., footer: ... }
   }) 
   // главная страница для пользователя
   .state('main.home', { 
      url: "/", 
      views: { header: ..., body: ..., footer: ... } 
   })
```

Такой вариант не удобен т.к. нужно привязываться к стейтам основного модуля (app), посоветуйте варианты реализации, так сказать BEST PRACTICE.

Comment: не понятно что вы хотите. Можете подробнее расписать **что** вы хотите получить?

Comment: нужно реализовать смену лейаута отображения в основном модуле глобально для всех остальных (children) модулей.

Comment: можно например именные view использовать

Comment: Отображения для гостя и авторизированного пользователя **полностью** отличаются на уровне каркаса страницы

Comment: и? я как раз и говорю про именные view

Comment: допустим есть страница home, в которой отображается контент "Hello world", после авторизации я хочу в основной шаблон добавить navbar, sidebar, footer и тд. но при этом ничего не делать со стейтом home

Comment: сделайте минимальный пример на plunkr того что есть сейчас с комментариями как бы хотелось. сейчас не понятно что вы имеете поэтому нельзя сказать как именно это можно (и нужно ли) изменить